# Free Code Obfuscater?

Tags: actionscript-3, obfuscation

i've never been really comfortable with the fact that all of my actionscript code is wide open for anyone to read from my published .swf files.

is there a free code obfuscater available?

Comment: So you'd like an open source code obfuscater so people CAN'T view your source code? Hmm..

Comment: i only mentioned open source with the aim of finding a popular solution.

Comment: Open Source and Obfuscation don't really go together well.

Comment: i got the irony already, thanks. i'm actually interested in starting an open source project to obfuscate AS3 code.  it wouldn't have to be closed in order to be effective since it would be mostly a application that would find-and-replace strings with random strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple google search returned several promising results.

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=actionscript%20obfuscator%20free

**ActionScript 3 Obfuscator**

http://www.irrlicht3d.org/pivot/entry.php?id=690

**Monokai ActionScript Obfuscator**

http://www.monokai.nl/blog/2006/08/02/actionscript-obfuscator/

Plus lots of choices that are at very reasonable prices.

Comment: the first one is no longer free.  the second one i'll have to further investigate but it looks questionable.  i guess i was more hoping for a widely adopted, popular solution.  i don't think that exists in free form.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for a SWF obfuscator, I just release one I developed for the last project I worked on. It's still a work in progress but it's open source, free, and it worked for my project. See the github site for full details on usage and license.

https://github.com/Teesquared/flasturbate